# Set value of ion-input to null when ion-checkbox is unchecked without [(ngModel)] angular 2 ionic 2

Tags: checkbox, ionic2, angular2-forms

I want to empty ion-input value when I uncheck ion-checkbox.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class = "Price">Fixed Price
        <ion-checkbox #FixedPrice></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    //I want to do something like that.
    <ion-input [value = ""]  = "!FixedPrice.checked"></ion-input>
    // i.e when I uncheck the ion-checkbox it should set the value of ion-input to "".
</ion-item>
```

If you need something else let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve this through a `(tap)` event.

*.compnent.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class = "Price">Fixed Price
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="fixedPrice" (tap)="fixedPriceCheck()"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="priceInput"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

*.component.ts

```
public fixedPrice: boolean = false;
public priceInput: string = '';

public fixedPriceCheck(): void {
    if (!this.fixedPrice) {
        this.priceInput = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this method. But I want it without [(ngModel)].